# How to fetch an element's font size in Xamarin UI-Test?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I want to get the Font size of an element using Xamarin UI-Test.

```cs
var deviceID_FontSize = App.Query(thisObject => thisObject.Id("deviceID")
                           .Invoke("getFontFeatureSettings"))[0];

Console.WriteLine("deviceID_FontSize: " + deviceID_FontSize );
```

The element is found and the test is not getting failed. But the output is null.

I am not sure if using `getFontFeatureSettings` method is proper or not.

Method reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:fontFeatureSettings

Please let me know what needs to be corrected, to get the proper output.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `getFontFeatureSettings` states 'the default is null'. So the value you got, can be correct. It's also correct to use the Java method name (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/cheatsheet#invoke-a-method-on-an-appresult-or-ui-element)

I don't understand why you use this method. I'd call [getTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getTextSize()).

```cs
var deviceID_FontSize = App.Query(thisObject => thisObject.Id("deviceID")
                           .Invoke("getTextSize"))[0];

Console.WriteLine("deviceID_FontSize: {0}", deviceID_FontSize);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sven-Michael Stübe. It worked. could you please let me know what method to use in order to get Font-family of an element